# Using multiple different .csv files in a loop to inject another r file

Tags: r, list, loops

I am still new with R, i will appreciate if someone give me an idea

```
setwd("~/lastversion_gwas_analysis/F_95/trial/") 
source("gwas.r") 
source("emma.r")
source("plots_gwas.r")
source('~/lastversion_gwas_analysis/f95_gwas.r')
#load Y values
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

**i can just put one .csv file as a Y value inside f95_gwas() r file.**

```
Y<- AT5G66980_AT4G10370.csv
Y[,1]<-as.numeric(Y[,1])
Y[,2]<-as.numeric(Y[,2])
f95_gwas(Y) #in this command gwas is running'''

### in here i tried to to put into list then call them separetly but i didnt find any solution yet. i need to use this for thousand differnt .csv file and put separelty inside f95_gwas () as a Y value

library(tidyverse)
library(fs)
source("gwas.r") 
source("emma.r")
source("plots_gwas.r")
source('~/lastversion_gwas_analysis/f95_gwas.r')
setwd("~/lastversion_gwas_analysis/F_95/trial/") 
file_paths<-fs::dir_ls("~/lastversion_gwas_analysis/F_95/trial/")
file_paths
##for loop
Y <- list()
for(i in seq_along(file_paths)){
  Y[[i]]<-read_csv(
    file=file_paths[[i]]
  )
}
Y<-set_names(Y, file_paths)
for (i in 1:length(Y))
{
  f95_gwas(Y[i])  #in this command gwas is running  
}
```

Comment: it is easier for us to troubleshoot you, if you provide more details regarding the actual error you receive. For now I assume the problem is in the last line of your code: `f95_gwas(Y[i])`. the argument `Y[i]` is a list with a single element. I guess the function `f95_gwas` does expect the element itself. try encasing the index with double squares like this: `f95_gwas(Y[[i]])`. This tells R that you want the i-th element, not a list.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wasnt sure in the first place put into .csv files into list. When i put into list, error is: Error in Y[,1]: incorrect number of dimension. f95_gwas() is expect each time single file that has to be named as a"Y". I just did not figure out how to put into loop these differnt .csv files then call separate Y into f95_gwas function. I just tried something for (i in 1:length(Y)) { f95_gwas(Y[i]) #in this command gwas is running } was an my assumption but didnt work with this.

Comment: R does not know about "files" this way. with `read_csv` you are reading the file at that adress and returning a dataframe. You collect those dataframes into a list. 
the apply family of functions (especially `lapply`) could be of interest for you.
`Y <- lapply(file_paths,read_csv)` could do the whole thing for you. It performs `read_csv` over the whole `file_paths`